# Cleaning iMac 24" (aluminium) with household products

Tags: cleaning, mac

The title is pretty self explanatory, how should I clean my iMac without having to break the bank with 'specialist' computer products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a little bit of 5% isopropyl alcohol + water on a cloth should do the trick. Rub lightly, in circular motions, no need to be obsessive.